# How to add QGraphicsDropShadowEffect to a Painter object

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QPainter` drawing an arrow, I want to add a drop shadow to the arrow. The [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html) seems like the class to implement, but I can't figure out how to do it.

It looks like the `draw` method may do it, but I'm gettin an error:

```
    painter.setPen(QPen(color(), thickness()));
    painter.drawLine(
      getShorterLine(points().first, points().second, thickness()));
    m_arrowPath = getArrowHead(points().first, points().second, thickness());
    painter.fillPath(m_arrowPath, QBrush(color()));
    m_DSEffect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();

    m_DSEffect->setBlurRadius(5);
    m_DSEffect->setOffset(0);
    m_DSEffect->setColor(QColor(Qt::black));
    m_DSEffect->draw(painter);
```

The error the IDE is telling me:

```
function "QGraphicsDropShadowEffect::draw" (declared at line 244 of "/Users/me/homebrew/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.2_1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qgraphicseffect.h") is inaccessible
```

Comment: The draw method is protected so it signals that warning to you. What element is QPainter painted on?

Comment: It looks like the QGraphicsDropShadowEffect is applied to QItems, not QPainter. I'm trying a drop-shadow by duplicating the painter shapes, changing to black, and shifting them. It's much more tedious.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm not sure what's being painted on. The code above is contained in a function `void ArrowTool::process(QPainter& painter, const QPixmap& pixmap)`. To be more clear, the arrow is draw on the screen as part of a screen-capture app.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]